# $\int \ x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$, by the substitution $x= \cos t$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, transformation, substitution

I have tried to determine $\int \ x\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$ using trigonometric

formula by the substition $x=\cos t$ I have got :

$$-\int \cos t \sin^2 t\,dt\tag{1}$$ for $\sin t > 0$ and $$ \int \cos t \sin^2 t\,dt\tag{2}$$  for $\sin t <0 $.

But both $(1)$ and $(2)$ have no standard mathematical function , then how do i can determine the titled integral using this method ?

Comment: Let $u=\sin(t)$ and $du=\cos(t)\,dt$  Then, we have $$\int \cos(t)\sin^2(t)\,dt=\int u^2\,du=\frac13u^3+C$$

Comment: I gave conditions , i just explained the absolute values

Comment: what about dt =d(cosx)dx  ?

Comment: Oh, dear! You're quite right. That's what I get for trying to do it in my head.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why not just let $u=1-x^2$?

Comment: 1-x² has trigonometric form this what let me to choose x=cos t

Comment: But $u=1-x^2$ is way easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assume $t\in[0,\pi]$.

Thus, $$\sqrt{1-x^2}=|\sin{x}|=\sin{x}.$$

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, which is in regards to $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: I answered what we need to do in this situation.

Comment: No, you didn't answer the question at all.  Take a look again.  "But both (1) and (2) have no standard mathematical function , then how do i can determine the titled integral using this method ?"  (-1) until you amend accordingly.

Comment: I saw it. I think It means that I said. You can  post your answer. I  want to see. Thank you!

Comment: Ross Millikan posted an answer that is appropriate and follows the comment I posted 5 minutes prior.

Comment: It's total wrong, I think. Because $\sqrt{\sin^2x}=|\sin{x}$|.

Comment: And the OP has accounted for the sign ambiguity.

Comment: @CameronBuie The question regards how to evaluate $(1)$ and $(2)$ and not how to resolve the sign ambiguity.  "But both $(1)$ and $(2)$ have no standard mathematical function , then how do i can determine the titled integral using this method?"

Comment: I think You did not understand the question. Bye.

Comment: "But both $(1)$ and $(2)$ have no standard mathematical function , then how do i can determine the titled integral using this method ?"  It seems clear that the OP is asking how one evaluates $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Comment: @MarkViola: You're right. Michael and I both made the same error in making the substitution, as far as I can tell. We both missed the $dx=-\sin t\,dt$ and came up with $\int\cos t\lvert\sin t\rvert\,dt.$

Comment: The substitution is right: $x=\cos{t}$. See please better the question and my post.

Answer (score 2):

Why don’t you use the substitution $t=1-x^2$?

Then $dt=-2xdx$ and your integral becomes:
$$\int x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=-\frac 12\int \sqrt tdt=\\=-\frac{\sqrt{t^3}}3+c=\color{red}{-\frac{\sqrt{(1-x^2)^3}}3+c}$$
It’s easier in this way.

Answer (score 1):

From $\int \cos t \sin^2 t dt$ you can use $u=\sin t, du=\cos t \ dt$ to get $\int u^2 du=\frac {u^3}3+C$ and backsubstitute.

Comment: Just like my comment 5 minutes ago ... ;-))